# Cómo convertir lista de listas en lista de strings en Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Imaginen que después de realizar la lectura de un fichero les queda una lista de esta forma:

```
>>> lista.take(2)
[['Hola ', 'qué ', 'tal'], ['muy ', 'bien']]
```

sin embargo, lo que quieren es obtener únicamente una lista de `strings` tal que:

```
['Hola qué tal', 'muy bien']
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta con realizar un mapeo con `lambda` sobre la lista en cuestión y operar con `join` en cada lista interior.

```
>>> lista = lista.map(lambda x : ''.join(x))
>>> lista.take(2)
['Hola qué tal', 'muy bien']
```